# XDocument Descendants, using elements value in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a problem, I can't get...and don't know what is wrong with it?

**the code:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
 {
  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(args[0] + "/?verb=GetRecord&metadataPrefix=p3dm&identifier=" + 1);
  doc.Save("doc.xml");
  var node = doc.Descendants("identifier");
  foreach (var n in node)
   {
    doc.Save("file_" + n.Value + ".xml");
   }
 }
```

**the doc.xml looks like:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <OAI-PMH xmlns="..." xmlns:xsi="..." xsi:schemaLocation="...">
      <responseDate>...</responseDate>
      <request verb="GetRecord" identifier="1"</request>
      <GetRecord>
        <record>
          <header>
            <identifier>1</identifier>
            <datestamp>...</datestamp>
          </header>
          <metadata>
            <P3DM xmlns="..." xsi:schemaLocation="...">
              <MODELINFOID>1</MODELINFOID>
              <TITLE>Roth</TITLE>
  ....
```

As we can see in doc.xml, there is  element with the value 1, and using Descendants and foreach...I would like to save same document but using  tag value to name my output file. What am I doing wrong. This code is just for testing.

Comment: What is the problem?  Do you expect us to guess it?  Read your mind?

Comment: no, when I run this all I get in save folder is doc.xml, no file_1.xml. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML has default namespace. You can use `XNamespace` plus element's local name to address an element in namespace :

```
......
//assume that the default namespace declared as <OAI-PMH xmlns="dummy.uri" ....>
XNamespace d = "dummy.uri";
var node = doc.Descendants(d+"identifier");
......
```